# If toggle one is switched off and then toggle two is switched off by the users then toggle one should be switched on

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am quite new to knockoutjs and I am trying to create two toggles. When toggle one is switched off and then toggle two is switched off by the user, toggle one should be switched on and vice versa.

```js
function alternatetogglesWithOrWithoutCreditRequests() {
    if (!viewModel.withPendingCreditRequests()) {
        viewModel.withoutPendingCreditRequests(true)
    }
    else if (!viewModel.withoutPendingCreditRequests()) {
        viewModel.withPendingCreditRequests(true)
    }
}
```

This code above does not work all the time because in both cases the `withPendingCreditRequests` and the `withoutPendingCredit` observables are false. The first statement will always be run in this scenario and it will not reach the else if statement.

Below is the HTML for the toggles:

```html
<div>
     <toggle-switch params="enable: invoiceFiltersActive, checked: withPendingCreditRequests, label: 'With Pending Credit Requests'"> 
     </toggle-switch>
</div>
<div>
     <toggle-switch params="enable: invoiceFiltersActive, checked: withoutPendingCreditRequests, label: 'Without Pending Credit Requests'">
     </toggle-switch>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout has the ability to [subscribe](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) to observables, so you can watch for changes. That would be a cleaner approach:

```
function ViewModel() {    
    this.checkboxOne = ko.observable(false);
    this.checkboxTwo = ko.observable(false);
    
    this.checkboxOne.subscribe(newVal => {
        if (!newVal && !this.checkboxTwo()) {
            this.checkboxTwo(true);
        }
    });
    
    this.checkboxTwo.subscribe(newVal => {
        if (!newVal && !this.checkboxOne()) {
            this.checkboxOne(true);
        }
    });
}
```

You can see it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/qad42z0w/).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is trying to still figure it out, I managed to find a way to make it work. On the html I have added data-bind to methods that handle clicks.

```js
function clickWithPendingCreditRequests() {
            if (!viewModel.withPendingCreditRequests() && !viewModel.withoutPendingCreditRequests()) {
                viewModel.withoutPendingCreditRequests(true)
            }
        }

        function clickWithoutPendingCreditRequests() {
            if (!viewModel.withoutPendingCreditRequests() && !viewModel.withPendingCreditRequests()) {
                viewModel.withPendingCreditRequests(true)
            }
        }
```

```html
 <div>
            <toggle-switch params="enable: invoiceFiltersActive, checked: withPendingCreditRequests, label: 'With Pending Credit Requests'" data-bind="clickWithPendingCreditRequests"></toggle-switch>
        </div>
        <div>
            <toggle-switch params="enable: invoiceFiltersActive, checked: withoutPendingCreditRequests, label: 'Without Pending Credit Requests'" data-bind="clickWithoutPendingCreditRequests"></toggle-switch>
        </div>
```

And on the view-model I have created those two methods with the following logic